# How to create an image database for HP IDOL OnDemand?

Tags: hp-idol-ondemand

For [Image-recognition](https://www.idolondemand.com/developer/apis/recognizeimages#indexes), we require to send 'enum' as a parameter. 
The description says that is a parameter for Image-database.
How to create such a database ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this response (I work for HPE Haven OnDemand), it is not currently possible to create your own image database with this API. The API is currently in Preview release, and uses the provided default corporatelogos public dataset. For a list of corporate logos used in the training set for the API, see [Corporate Logo Training Set](https://www.idolondemand.com/developer/docs/CorporateLogoSet.html).